# Laravel / Eloquent - Belongs to many with different relationship

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

So basically, I have the following tables:

Cars for sale:

> id, make, total_cost_price, reference_number

Cars to let:

> id, make, total_rental_price, reference_number

Car Features:

> id, feature, created_at, updated_at

car_car_features

> car_reference, car_features_id

What I'm trying to do is make a join (using Eloquents belongsToMany) between `Cars for sale/let` and `features` and I'm using the following in the 'CarsSale' model:

```
  public function features()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\CarFeatures', 
        'car_car_features', 'car_reference', 
        'reference_number');
  }
```

However, this is not returning any values. I can't seem to figure out why it wouldn't since the join tables are linked?

Any ideas?

Comment: Wouldnt it be better to have one table cars with column type (sale/let)?

Comment: @Autista_z Yes but would require a lot of changes and the table i posted was a condensed version and has a lot more fields.

Comment: @Autista_z Is it not possible through the join / link table?

Comment: @Phorce it is impossible to do what you are asking because it is impossible to differentiate between "Cars for sale" and "Cars to let" by only checking "car_reference" since it may refer to either table and you don't know which one. If you do insist on doing this then you need to modify the pivot to include the car type and use [polymorphic relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations)